# BATCH - The Syntax Of The Command Is Incorrect

Tags: batch-file, syntax

SEE THE FULL CODE HERE: http://pastebin.com/nu7u5XTC

I am using the 'choice' command to read the user's key so that the program knows what to do.

```
@ECHO OFF
setlocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion
goto initialise

:initialise
cls
set /a x=6
set /a y=10
set /a oldx=%x%
set /a oldy=%y%
REM Place all of the grass blocks...
rem PaintScreen 2

:choicelistener

set /a oldx=%x%
set /a oldy=%y%

choice /c wasdWASDpqezxm /CS >NUL

if %ERRORLEVEL%==1 goto moveNorth

if %ERRORLEVEL%==2 (
REM Go west.
if %facing.x%.%facing.y%.occupied==true (
REM There is a block there.
goto choicelistener
) ELSE (
REM There was no block there.
set /a x=%x%-1
set prevmove=a
rem ChangeColor 2 0
goto checker
)

if %ERRORLEVEL% 3 (
REM Go south.
if %facing.x%.%facing.y%.occupied==true (
REM There is a block there.
goto choicelistener
) ELSE (
REM There was no block there.
set /a y=%y%+1
set prevmove=s
rem ChangeColor 2 0
goto checker
)
```

That is the part of code that breaks. I get the error
"The syntax of the command is incorrect."

I have researched this for two hours, other people have has this problem, but none of their solutions have helped me. Any suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: Type `choice /?` at a command prompt and hit Enter.

Comment: The code you've posted doesn't generate any errors. You've simplified it too much. Also, if you really put the code to check user input at the very bottom like that, it will never work since `%errorlevel%` is based on the most recent command run, in this case `set /a oldy=%y%` which will always set `%errorlevel%` to 0.

Comment: The command you're using **does not match** what the help shows. Read it again.

Comment: In the updated code you've posted, you have lines like `if %ERRORLEVEL% 1 (goto moveNorth)`. These should say `if %ERRORLEVEL% equ 1 (goto moveNorth)` - although the code will still never work the way you want it to because the errorlevel commands have to be placed immediately after the `choice` command.

Comment: Change `@echo off` to `@echo on`. The line before you get the error should be the part of your code causing the problem. Your choice command is fine.

Comment: Ken White, what am I missing ?

Comment: Does the sample you're providing us also have the issue? Because I don't get an error when I run it. It could be an issue with the arguments for PaintScreen or ChangeColor.

Comment: I see the problem now. It's just like Rafael said. You're missing a second `)` at the end of each of your errorlevel checks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't forget to close the parentheses..

```
...
goto checker
)
)
```

On your two verifications.

Comment: I have the moveNorth label further down the script. I excluded it so the code would not be too long.

Comment: No, I tried that before and I just tried again, it does not work.

Comment: As I've said before, your code will never work properly because the %errorlevel% commands have to be **immediately** after the choice statement.